# Performance Decrease After Using cx_Freeze 5.0

Tags: python, executable, cx-freeze

As stated in the title, after converting a python (3.4) program to an exe through cx_Freeze 5.0, I've received a huge performance hit. The code used to take about 70 seconds to run, but now takes around 480. What could be a cause of this? I'm importing fractions and time if that is of any concern. CPU usage has not changed.

Comment: Can you provide the code that results in this performance degradation?